# How to 'open sync URL' for realm object server?

Tags: realm

I am new in '**Realm-Object-Server**'. I can see my data by '**Realm-Browser**' for mac that '**each user**' has a database in the **realm-object-server**. I need to see **all users'** data in a single '**database**' in the object-server. Is it really possible to access all users' data into a single DB. I think, I will achieve this by clicking '**[open syn URL]**' or '**Open Realm URL**'[see-image].

Additionally, what is the difference between 'open sync URL' and 'Connect to objet- server'

[see-image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sMK0E.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

"Connect to Object Server" option allows you to use admin credentials to access any realm on the Object Server. When you connect to the server you can double click any realm to open it.

"Open Sync URL" allows you to open a specific user realm by specifying it's path and user's credentials. You can specify path like `realm://server_address/~/realm_name` and it will be resolved automatically.

Comment: my sync url is 'realm://http://emmabiz.com:9080/~/VWF_DEV'. but i cant login by browser. Though, my credential is right by which i can login into my app but not into realm browser

Comment: what error message are you getting? and what type of credentials do you use?